# how can I grant a web app access to read IoT Hub information

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I need to develop a Java web app that a user can subscribe to from the App Store, and upon login, they grant the app access to view device details on IoT Hubs that they have available to them in their cloud environment.

Ive been able to access all the information necessary so far, via the management API, and I understand that each IoT Hub has its own domain that I need to post API requests to, in order to get device specific information. My question is, how do I grant the app access, to acquire a token to access those Hub APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Access policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#access-control-and-permissions). What you are looking for is `registryRead`. This enables the user to only read all device information but not make any changes. However: You cannot filter, which devices that policy can see - its always all devices in the IoT Hub.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. In my web app, I authenticate a user, via the scope "https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation". This gets me to the point of being able to get a listing of the IoT Hubs. So would it be possible for the user to grant registreyRead access to the app when they initially sign in?

Comment: not directly, no. Since `registryRead` is not a AAD-managed permission. You need a SAS token for that. But you could certainly build a service, that has the permission to generate those tokens and then use that token in your user session

Comment: would this require an OBO flow?

Comment: What is OBO flow?

Comment: Azure On-Behalf-Of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

Comment: Again, these access polices do not support AAD so this does not apply

Comment: Could you tell me if a user-delegated SAS would be what I need? Im referencing the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas Im reading that making the request to a user delegation key that I would need to sign the SAS, are only available to resources in the blob service?